# Подсчет минимального возможного количества замен у числа "x" по заданному алгоритму: x=m*n; x=m+n-2, где m и n - какие-то натуральные числа

Tags: python, алгоритм

***Пояснение***:
Есть натуральное число `x`, его можно представить как произведение двух натуральных чисел `m` и `n` (`x=m*n`). Далее `x` нужно заменить на `m+n-2` (`x=m+n-2`). И это все необходимо выполнять, пока `x` не станет равно `1`

`x` может быть в пределах миллиарда

***Пример***:
В программу поступило число 6.

```
6=3*2   3+2-2=3
6=6*1   6+1-2=5

3=3*1   3+1-2=2
5=5*1   5+1-2=4

2=2*1   2+1-2=1 - x=1, останавливаемся (до единицы мы дошли за 3 замены)
4=2*2   2+2-2=2
```

***Мои попытки***

```
from math import sqrt

def isint(n):
    return not(n%1)

def f(n):
   count = 0
   while(True):
      x=sqrt(n)
      if(n<=1):
         return count
      if(isint(x)):
         n=x+x-2
      else:
         x=int(x)
         while(isint(n/x)==False):
            x=x-1
         if(x<=0):
             return count
         n=int((n/x)+x-2)
      count+=1
print('Минимальное кол-во попыток для числа 6 = ',f(6))
```

*P.S. Мой алгоритм делает ошибки, но некоторые числа он все же считает*

Comment: Хм, какой-то странный алгоритм у вас

Comment: Ага, хотя идея ясна, чем множители ближе друг к другу, тем меньше из сумма. Но ведь это не гарантирует, что чем меньше n тем меньше шагов потребуется, поэтому не всегда будет правильный результат. Думаю, для начала нужен полный перебор.

Comment: а зачем это надо? Просто интересно (:
полный алгоритм увы долгий.
1) разложить число на простые множители
2) получить все варианты представления числа как произведение двух чисел m+n-2
3) плюс рекурсия с хранением промежуточных результатов!?
4) выбираем минимум итераций.....

Comment: Есть закономерность, что чем больше число имеет делителей, тем меньше требуется шагов, соответственно для простых числе требуется больше шагов, чем для составных, но как этим воспользоваться, ведь число шагов также растет и при увеличении входного числа. Можно, конечно, на каждом шаге выбирать "самое непростое" число, но кто гарантирует, что это даст правильный результат? Как это доказать и вообще возможно ли?

Comment: Подозреваю, что задача сводится к ТРПЧ :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Я питон не знаю... Но на С++ решение этой задачи - вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int MAXSIZE = 1000000000;

unsigned char m[MAXSIZE+1];

int count(int x, int level = 0, int curmin = MAXSIZE)
{
    if (level > curmin) return -1; // Отсечение - нет смысла лезть вглубь
                                   // при наличии более короткого решения
    if (x == 1) return 0;
    if (m[x])
    {
        return m[x];               // Сохраненное значение
    }
    int res = MAXSIZE;
    for(int i = sqrt(x)+0.1; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        if (x%i) continue;
        int k = count(i+x/i-2, level+1, res);
        if (k < 0) continue;
        if (k < res) { res = k; }
    }
    return m[x] = res+1;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : MAXSIZE;
    if (n > MAXSIZE) n = MAXSIZE;
    cout << n << ":  " << count(n) << endl;

    int cur = m[n];
    while (n > 1)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i*i <= n; ++i)
        {
            if (n%i) continue;
            if (m[i+n/i-2] == cur-1)
            {
                n = i+n/i-2;
                --cur;
                cout << i << " ";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Как видите, на ideone [решило миллиард](https://ideone.com/ZXbid7) за 0.04с :)

Ключевые моменты:
1. Перебор с отсечением
2. Начинаем со значений, близких к корню
3. Мемоизация

Кстати, до миллиона включительно самая длинная цепочка - 11, так что глубокой рекурсии явно не стоит ожидать.

Comment: обратный цикл имеет смысл только в паре с отсечением.
Круто. будем знать )

Comment: у меня возникают проблемы с памятью (128 Мб), можно ли как-нибудь то исправить избавившись от рекурсии?

Comment: Проблема не в рекурсии. а в массиве для мемоизации. Замените `unsigned char m[MAXSIZE+1];` на `map<int,unsigned char>m;`, и дело в шляпе :) - правда, немного упадет производительность, не не так чтоб очень сильно...

Comment: Вот - https://ideone.com/UayUDV - 0.12с вместо 0.04

Comment: А тут - https://ideone.com/zyJ5Y1 - и вовсе без мемоизации, но уже за 0.42с... Но при этом нельзя само решение показать - только длину цепочки.

Answer (score 6):

Ваш алгоритм основан на предположении, что если `a < b`, то `f(a) <= f(b)`, но это не всегда так, например `f(7) = 4`, а `f(8) = 3`.

Для начала, думаю, стоит начать с полного перебора, если ничего лучше не придумаете, то добавьте мемоизацию.

Вот простой пример полного рекурсивного перебора на C#:

```
static int GetStepsCount(int x)
{
    // Граничное условие выхода
    if (x <= 1) return 0;
    // Делаем один шаг и прибавляем к нему
    return 1 +
        Enumerable
            // Для всех m от 1 до корня из x
            .Range(1, (int)Math.Sqrt(x))
            // Где m является делителем x
            .Where(m => x % m == 0)
            // Вычислить GetStepsCount
            .Select(m => GetStepsCount(m + x / m - 2))
            // И взять среди них минимум
            .Min();
}
```

Если алгоритм требуется выполнять для входных чисел бОльших, чем пару сотен, то мемоизация неизбежна, т.к. полный перебор работает очень долго. Вот пример, с использованием словаря:

```
static Dictionary<int, int> memory = new Dictionary<int, int>();
static int GetStepsCount(int x)
{
    if (x <= 1) return 0;
    if (!memory.ContainsKey(x))
        memory[x] = 1 +
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, (int)Math.Sqrt(x))
                .Where(m => x % m == 0)
                .Select(m => GetStepsCount(m + x / m - 2))
                .Min();
    return memory[x];
}
```

Расход памяти небольшой, но скорость выполнения возрастает значительно.

Comment: о как шарпак подрос. только с ясностью происходящего - надо привыкнуть )))  читабельность еще та...
Я место где x=m+n-2 так и не нашел...
А оно есть?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, интересно, когда вы последний раз его видели, ибо Linq подвезли еще в C# 3.0, а это было в 2007 г.

Comment: и точно-точно в 2007 году было все от Enumerable до .Min();
???
Я последний раз шарп видел в 2012

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, да, все 4 использованных мною метода доступны с .NET 3.5, а значит их завезли одновременно с C# 3.0

Comment: ну круто. значит плохо я в 2010 изучал Linq ))
но про  x=m+n-2 все равно не вижу...
магия шарпа ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, ну как же, смотрите внимательнее: `m + x / m - 2`, т.е. `n = x / m`

Comment: ыыыыыыы ) ну да.
красиво. надеюсь кто то ответ на "вызов" ;-)
с запоминанием это в пайтоне автоматически одним декоратором решается, а вот столько сахара как в линке пока может и нет....
Ставлю +1  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import functools 
from math import sqrt

@functools.lru_cache()
def f(x):
    if x <=1: return 0
    return 1 + min([ f(m + x // m - 2)  for m in range(1,int(sqrt(x))+1) if x%m ==0])
```

Это сразу с кэшированием ;-)
Так что єто Пайтон подрос получается )))
кстати, f(1024) дает 7.
Без @functools.lru_cache() считается минут 20, а с @functools.lru_cache() - 2-3 секунды !!

Comment: @Андрей NOP
сверим часы?
сколько там на  1024 получается?
А то фиг знает как проверять правильность работы кода? ;-)
Эй там, на шарпе? ;-)

Comment: Да, 7, всё верно. Неужели питон медленнее шарпа? У меня выполняется за 8 мс.

Comment: @Андрей NOP: Сча проверю. я ж на ощущения говорил )) от ввода до вывода. Но вполне вероятно - медленнее. Я ж на одном ядре все считаю, а у вас - все ж лучше ;-)____________________________________
Итого:  0.021 сек. то есть в три раза хуже, да? на стареньком AMD Athlon II X250 3Ghz. Благодарю за общение и хороших выходных!!

Comment: У меня тоже на одном ядре (i7-7700HQ), многопоточность, боюсь, не даст выигрыша, ибо надо потокобезопасный словарь. Ну да, в 2 раза точно быстрее. А в абсолютных величинах, в общем-то, разница незначительна

Comment: Не работает для больших чисел:   `return 1 + min([ f(m + x // m - 2)  for m in range(1,int(sqrt(x))+1) if x%m ==0])`
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Интересно, в условии - *x может быть в пределах миллиарда* - что по времени даст для миллиарда? :)

Comment: @Harry, это новое условие. У меня уже на паре тысяч падает со стэкоферфлоу. Надо раскрутить рекурсию, но всё равно сомневаюсь, что для миллиарда это сработает. Да и памяти для словаря надо уже гигабайты

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну, я на VC++ до миллиона дотянул, на 10 миллионах начался затык по времени... Дальше даже не пытался.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Да, но если миллион посчитало за какие-то 2.5 секунды (решение - делители 100 51 13  5 3 2 1 - это так, для проверки... вдруг я где-то ошибся?), то для 10000000 - 76 секунд (решение 1000 94 11 4 3 2 1).

Comment: @Harry - какие то странные делители у млн - 51, 13, 3 !?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets 1000000=100*10000 => 10000+100-2=10098; 10098=51*198 => 51+198-2=247; 247=13*19 => ... - ну, понятно? Кстати, миллиард взят...

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Только что дал свой ответ на вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770528/195342