# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded - как преодолеть?

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть задача в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770303/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-x-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8); есть ее решение, где по изяществу Python "победил" C#, но вот у же на х=512 вылетает RecursionError:
что посоветуете, отцы? Как преодолеть, если хочется посчитать для х=1024 скажем?

```
import functools 
from math import sqrt

@functools.lru_cache()
def f(x):
    if x <=1: return 0
    return 1 + min([ f(m + x // m - 2)  for m in range(1,int(sqrt(x))+1) if x%m ==0])
```

добавлю после первого ответа:

### Кто предложит как изменить алгоритм?

Кстати. Добавил количество рекурсии до 5000. Получается странная фигня. для 1024 считает, делая 3600 итераций, а для 2048 - "выбивает" интерпретатор на 1000+ рекурсии. Вообще не пойму - в чем проблема....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я python не знаю... Но на С++ решение этой задачи - вот в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770528/195342

Как видите, на ideone решило миллиард за 0.04с без особого напряжения по стеку.

Ключевые моменты:

1. Перебор с отсечением

Мы сразу отсекаем особо длинные рекурсии, которые, очевидно, не приведут к оптимальному решению.

2. Начинаем со значений, близких к корню

Такая вот эвристика - там цепочки самые короткие, и мы сразу найдем решение, которое позволит отсечь большое количество заведомо плохих решений и не лезть глубоко в рекурсии.

3. Мемоизация

Позволит не считать повторно то, что уже посчитано. Кстати, подозреваю, что она не сильно и нужна, но сохранилась с предыдущих попыток решить задачу. Возможно, имеет смысл заменить массив, все-таки с немалым размером, на `map` (словарь). Это уже надо проверять и экспериментировать, но увы, сегодня на это уже нет времени.

Да, это не так красиво выглядит... Но зато решает с очень малой глубиной рекурсии и очень быстро.

Еще раз извиняюсь за незнание python... Вроде у малого в школе на следующий год обещают его преподавать - ну, вот тогда придется изучить и исправиться :)

**Update**

Использовал вместо массива на миллиард байт просто `map<int,unsigned char>`. На моей машине миллиард вместо 77ms стал считаться 104ms, но зато при этом потребовалось только 44675 элементов в `map`. Экономию памяти оцените сами :)

При полном отказе от мемоизации не получается восстановить решение, но сама величина - 8 - для миллиарда находится за примерно 580ms.

Comment: Попробую переписать на пайтон ваш алгоритм ;-)
а можно в том алгоритме (приведенном в другом вопросе) добавить коммент где именно "отсечение"? 
Мемоизацию выполняет @functools.lru_cache()
перевернуть цикл - не проблема )
Но меня удивляет что интерпретатор "выбивает" без сообщения об ошибке при параметре более 2000 в любом случае.
То ли с пайтоном что, то ли с моими мозгами )))
Благодарю!

Comment: Указал, где отсечение.

Comment: вот здесь ваш код переписан мной на питоне ;-)
https://ideone.com/zZXNtI
чтоб легче было учить с сыном ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Спасибо! напомните к сентябрю :)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему вы преодолели порог глубины рекурсии.

> exception RecursionError This exception is derived from RuntimeError.
> It is raised when the interpreter detects that the maximum recursion
> depth (see sys.getrecursionlimit()) is exceeded.
>
> New in version 3.5: Previously, a plain RuntimeError was raised.

[Ссылка на источник](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Решением вашей проблемы будет ручное указание глубины рекурсии
вызовом метода **sys.setrecursionlimit(limit**):

> sys.setrecursionlimit(limit)
>
> Set the maximum depth of the Python
> interpreter stack to limit. This limit prevents infinite recursion
> from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.
>
> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to
> set the limit higher when they have a program that requires deep
> recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be
> done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.
>
> If the new limit is too low at the current recursion depth, a
> RecursionError exception is raised.
>
> Changed in version 3.5.1: A RecursionError exception is now raised if
> the new limit is too low at the current recursion depth.

[Ну и ссылка на источник.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)

Comment: Автор понимает, что такое `RecursionError`. Его интересует как исправить алгоритм так, чтобы не получать эту ошибку, не потеряв изящества решения. А увеличение лимита - это не решение, это костыль.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev: Извиняюсь. Не правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev лично я понял фразу "Как преодолеть" тоже именно как "Как увеличить лимиты" (но ответ вчера писать поленился)

Answer (score 2):

Я размещу код, предложенный @Harry на С++, переведенный мною на Python для сохранения "тематики" языка на странице. Решение принадлежит ему.
В любом случае - как всегда решает на язык, а мозг Ж-)

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

MAXSIZE = 1000000000
m = np.zeros(MAXSIZE+1, dtype=np.int16)

def f(x, level=0, curmin = MAXSIZE) -> int: 
    if level > curmin: return -1 # Отсечение - нет смысла лезть вглубь
                                 # при наличии более короткого решения
    if x == 1: return 0
    if m[x]: return m[x]      # Сохраненное значение

    res = MAXSIZE;
    for i in range(int(sqrt(x))+1, 0, -1):
        if x%i: continue;
        k = f(i+x//i-2, level+1, res);
        if k < 0: continue;
        if k < res:  res = k
        m[x] = res+1
    return m[x]

n = int(input("дай целое!"))
print( n, ": ", f(n))
```

## вывод подробностей решения:

```
cur = m[n]
while n>1:
    for i in range(1,int(sqrt(n))+1):
        if n%i: continue
        if m[i+n//i-2] == cur-1:
            n = i+n//i-2
            cur -=1
            print(i, end=' ')
            break
print("")
```

Разница между этим кодом и кодом приведенным в вопросе - такова.
Он работает для числа 1 000 000 000,  в то время как исходный код "вырубал" интерпретатор уже на 2048.
Ручное кэширование оказалось надежнее встроенного в пайтон, и - важнее всего -отсечение неправильных вариантов заметно сократило время.