# Проблема с использованием потока

Tags: python, многопоточность, рекурсия

Задача состоит в нахождении мостов. Алгоритм основан на рекурсии. До 10000 тыс элементов работает все нормально. Но, если больше, то переполняется стек.

```
threading.stack_size(67108864) 

thread = threading.Thread(target=main)

thread.start()
```

Нашел вот это в инете. Помогло, но теперь стало выводить какие то лишние цифры, и цифры которые вообще за пределом возможного ответа.
Если просто увелить `sys.setrecursionlimit(2**20)` до макс размера не помогает. А вот если  написать 3 строки(которые thread), то программа хотя бы работает. Но выводиться как и правильные ответы, так  и неправильные.

Comment: Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой в "игрушечном" примере.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770386/recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-как-преодолеть

Comment: Меня интересует почему,берутся ответы которые никак вообще не могут там быть.У меня ответ берется из словаря по ключу, так вот такого ключа даже нет,а ошибка не выскакивает по этому поводу никакая

Comment: О - это уже очень интересно.
Но это другой вопрос.
Попробуйте задать его в отдельном вопросе с примерами кода и неправильного вывода, если структура программы позволяет сделать обозримый полный пример...
Или сымитируйте такую же ошибку в "игрушечном" примере.

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой в "игрушечном" примере.
[RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded - как преодолеть?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770386/recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)
Решение было в том, что надо менять алгоритм и хранить свой кэш. 
В вашем случае - все "хуже".
Однако можно заменить рекурсию на явную работу со своим стеком.
Проблема заключается в размере стека, выделяемое ОС под приложение. Так по умолчанию в винде 2МБ, а в линуксах - 8МБ.
Ручное изменение этих параметров в винде - хлопотно. Надо патчить сам python.exe.  Думаю - легче запустить под линуксами...