# Интерпретатор перезагружается без сообщения об ошибке - как же ее искать?

Tags: python, отладка, рекурсия, visual-studio-2017

Улучшая [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770386/recursionerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) возник вопрос о поведении интерпретатора. Он затыкается без сообщений и перезагружается. Вот код с промежуточной печатью, который пока можно и пропустить. Суть вопроса в текстах:

```
import time
import sys
import functools 
from math import sqrt

#print(f' sys.getrecursionlimit()={sys.getrecursionlimit()}')
i=0
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

@functools.lru_cache()
def f(x):
    global i
    i +=1
    if i%250==0: print(i)
    if x <=1: return 0
    return 1 + min([ f(m + x // m - 2)  for m in range(1,int(sqrt(x))+1) if x%m==0])

x = int(input("дай целое!"))
t0 = time.clock()
print( f(x))
t1 = time.clock()
print (t1-t0, '  i=', i)
```

вот что странно: при вводе например 1024 он полностью отрабатывает и выдает следующее:

```
дай целое!1024
250
500
750
...
3250
3500
7
0.12052656332407201   i= 3636
```

то есть ответ 7 получается за 3636 итераций за 0.12 сек, а при вводе числа 1040 "затыкается без слов" на 1000+ рекурсии !?!

```
дай целое!1040
250
500
750
1000

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
```

В связи с этим два вопроса
**1) почему так

2) как вообще тестировать/отлаживать рекурсивные функции при отсутствии хоть какого то сообщения от интерпритатора?**

Обидная добавка:  а в MS VS Python - где отключен GIL - алгоритм срабатывает "через раз". То есть "чистый" пайтон затыкается ВСЕГДА на числе 1040, а тот же пайтон из MS VS 2017 - то выдает результат, а то "вешается" на той же 1000+ рекурсий.
Как это возможно и как преодолеть, если оно то считает то не считает и вешается без слов? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете поставить внутри функции условие и breakpoint только если оно выполнитсяю

Comment: 1- maxsize=None в lru_ cache() 2- [] внутри min не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

Начнем по порядку.

Я протестил Ваш код у себя, но правда под линуксом. Переставало отрабатывать после ввода 2500. При этом падало с большим стектрейсом (ожидаемо). После того, как я поднял размер рекурсии до 100000, начало принимать и обрабатывать и 6000 (но я не дождался ответа). На 7000 и больше падает с ошибкой сегментации (это надо отдельно смотреть, и это похоже на последний Ваш скриншот).

Глобальная переменная i, которая "якобы считает глубину рекурсии", на самом деле считает кол-во вызовов фукции `f()`. На каждом уровне рекурсии функция рекурсивно вызывает себя много раз. То есть, граф вызовов похож на дерево. И если на каждом вызове делать по два вызова, то на 10 вложенности будет всего 1024 вызова. А если делать по 10, то 1 с десятю нулями. Это собственно и объясняет Ваше непонимания.

То есть, ещё раз, почти везде где Вы пишите "такая то иттерация" или "на таком то уровне рекурсии", нужно читать "при таком кол-ве вызовов". Что бы считать уровень рекурсии правильно, нужно при выходе с функции уменьшеать i на 1.

> как вообще тестировать/отлаживать рекурсивные функции при отсутствии хоть какого то сообщения от интерпритатора?

видимо нужно использовать "интерпрЕтатор":). Я думаю, что скорее всего у студии есть дополнительные ограничители. В случае с с++ мне удавалось простой программой (которая просто в цикле создавала потоки) заводить студию в полное зависание.

> То есть "чистый" пайтон затыкается ВСЕГДА на числе 1040, а тот же пайтон из MS VS 2017 - то выдает результат, а то "вешается" на той же 1000+ рекурсий.

А тут все очень просто. В случае с "чистым питоном" у Вас "чистый эксперимент". То есть, входные данные почти всегда идентичные. А вот в случае студии это не так. Вполне возможно, что студия по свои цели (например, индексирование или проверка апдейтов) "скушала" немного памяти... и все.

Comment: скушала немного памяти - и это дало возможность сработать там, где чистый пайтон вешается? серьезно?
Благодарю за проделанный труд. Я запостил этот вопрос на сайте python.org.
Сказали что вся проблема в том что на винде под стек приложения выделяют 2 МБ любому приложению, а на линуксах - 8 и этот параметр регулируемый. Нашел как можно в EXEруками поменять размер стека на винде для python.exe.
Но - вопрос остался - как же искать ошибку даже с помощью интерпрЕтатора? 
Если он при падении даже не гавкнул?

Comment: я нигде не писал словосочетание "глубина рекурсии".
Я понимаю, как работает моя программа и что именно вычисляется в  "i".
Но не отчаивайтесь.
Глубина рекурсии более 8 на 1000 не встречалась. В том то и прикол )

Comment: может все же сможете дать ответна вопросы:
1)  как же так - падает без сообщения?
2)  как отловить эту ситуацию средствами пайтона? как понять, что именно из-за стека пайтона? может какие промежуточные чеки размера стека?

Comment: У меня под линуксом он ругается и еще как. С большим стектрейсом. А вот под виндой где то стектрейс прячется... Надо его искать. Но когда интерпретатор крешится... тут уже интерпретатор не поможет. Тут нужно брать в руки gdb и смотреть. По поводу стека - раньше было по мегабайту. А сейчас под линуксом проверил - да, уже по 8 дают. Но может это из-за 64битной архитектруры.

Comment: я перетестил. Глубина рекурсии обычно больше входного числа. На 1000 получилось 1000. На 2000 получилось 6332.

Comment: это все здорово. Однако вопрос не в том.
как отличить этот тип ошибок, скажем от проблем с перегревом памяти или еще с чем?
Или - "если интерпретатор вылетел без слов - значит стек переполнился?" 
И только в этом случае?

Comment: кстати - нормальное решение задачи (лучший алгоритм) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770303/Подсчет-минимального-возможного-количества-замен-у-числа-x-по-заданному-алгори
если вдруг интересно.
Считает до 1 000 000 000

Comment: да, вы правы по сути и даже в мелочах. Но вопрос про "молчание пайтона" и про то какими средствами можно прояснить причину падения

Comment: В первом случае это особенность "оболочки". Во втором там падение. И это явно не тихо. Но это уже вопрос к gdb