# Как искать ошибку, если интерпретатор падает без сообщения об ошибке?

Tags: python, отладка, рекурсия

Наверное я был многословен в похожем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770525/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).
Опишу его здесь. Какие есть инструменты отладки/поиска ошибки/причины падения, если интерпретатор перезагружается, не выдавая никакого сообщения?

Посоветуйте инструменты для контроля памяти или еще что?
В дополнение скажу, что речь идет о рекурсивной функции.

Больше подробностей - в приведенном вопросе по ссылке. Привожу код, чтобы вы могли повторить его на своей машине. Алгоритм правильный...

```
import time
import sys
import functools 
from math import sqrt

#print(f' sys.getrecursionlimit()={sys.getrecursionlimit()}')
i=0
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

@functools.lru_cache()
def f(x):
    global i
    i +=1
    if i%250==0: print(i)
    if x <=1: return 0
    return 1 + min([ f(m + x // m - 2)  for m in range(1,int(sqrt(x))+1) if x%m==0])

x = int(input("дай целое!"))
t0 = time.clock()
print( f(x))
t1 = time.clock()
print (t1-t0, '  i=', i)
```

вот что странно: при вводе например 1024 он полностью отрабатывает и выдает следующее:

```
дай целое!1024
250
500
750
...
3250
3500
7

0.12052656332407201   i= 3636
```

то есть ответ 7 получается за 3636 итераций за 0.12 сек, а при вводе числа 1040 "затыкается без слов" на 1000+ рекурсии !?!

```
дай целое!1040
250
500
750
1000

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
```

Если кому интересно  -  постановка задачи - здесь:
[Подсчет минимального возможного количества замен у числа "x" по заданному алгоритму: x=m*n; x=m+n-2, где m и n - какие-то натуральные числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770303/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-x-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8)

========
Добавлено сегодня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом на идеоне отрабатывает для 1000000:
https://ideone.com/ctx92s
и?
Как понять причину

Comment: Интерпретатор в принципе не может перезагружаться сам по себе. Сам по себе он может только упасть. Значит его кто-то перезагружает, а кто - вам виднее

Comment: А когда он падает сам по себе, то как минимум всегда есть код выхода. А в примере по ссылке скорее всего обычный сегфолт из-за выхода за пределы стека

Comment: @andreymal наверное я неправильно использую термины. Могу привести еще раз код, и результат. Но это будет дубликат вопроса, указанного по ссылке.  При некоторых N  код работает и причем правильно, а потом - "молча затыкается".
А как проверить что этот "сегфолт" случился и по какой причине?

Comment: Обильно добавить в код скрипта отладочное логирование и анализировать лог в моменты затыков.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev - вот я и задаю вопрос в надежде на конкретніе рекомендации - что за отладочное логирование добавить чтобы понять "что где когда". Знал бы  -  не спрашивал ;-)

Comment: Что конкретно происходит с вашим скриптом? Он повисает? Или молча завершается?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил часть данных из исходного вопроса по ссылке.
Молча завершается, дорабатывая до 1000 рекурсивных вызовов, хотя иногда дорабатывает и до 3000+ вызовов. Правда там только степени 2.... Грешу на память, но как проверить?!??!?!

Comment: чем запускаете?  Я запустил и у меня все ок.

Comment: @AndrioSkur из IDLE Python на Windows10. В вопросе по ссылке есть скриншоты из MS VS2017 Python
Ну запустите на 2080 - что получится....
на 1024 и у меня идет, на 1040 - перезагружается...
Вопрос в принципе - понять объективную причину

Comment: x = 2000 и все ок. http://rextester.com/HTMH48042 Киньте мне такую же ссылку но с крешем

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, пока вы не перепишете рекурсивный алгоритм в итеративный  - это вам не сильно поможет. Вы все равно "упретесь" в Stack Overflow - так даже сайт назвали на котором мы общаемся ;).

Comment: @AndrioSkur  вот два скриншота
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HugPq.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYibA.png
  из VS на 1040 как с крєшем так и без него )

Comment: @MaxU - вопрос ведь не в алгоритме. Все уже переписано и летает.
Вопрос в том как отличить что это именно  Stack Overflow. Я  имено хочу знать - что это именно переполнение стека
 и не понимаю, как это интерпретатор перезагружается молча и хочу понять причину его поведения.
Я - немного перфекционист ;-)

Comment: Ну в `VS` кривой интерпритатор, дальше то что? Он точно также может падать и без рекурсии

Comment: @AndrioSkur  Дело в том что позавчера у меня падало как в IDLE VS 2017, а вчера я обновил версию пайтона  с  3,6,2  на   3,6,3 
блин и действительно теперь работает ...
Мля то есть вопрос остался, хотя вопроса и нет....
Ведь и у других падало на 1040 вчера...

Comment: но на 1000000 у меня перезагружается, а на ideone - работает...
https://ideone.com/ctx92s

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, можете посмотреть подробности в `Windows Event Viewer` -> `Windows Logs -> Application` и открыть `bug` в Python... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU 0xc00000fd )))Теперь по ходу сносить пайтон и ставить заново?

Answer (score 5):

Самый лучший способ выяснить, что не так со скриптом - [отладчик](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Но этот способ трудно применим, если скрипт работает долго, выполняет множество действий, а неправильное поведение возникает не всегда и непредсказуемо. Если нештатное поведение такого скрипта - это зависание, то можно попробовать сделать вызов отладчика в [обработчике сигнала](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html):

```
import signal

def run_pdb(signal, frame):
    import pdb
    pdb.Pdb().set_trace(frame)    


def do_something():  # Основная логика
    ...    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, run_pdb)
    do_something()
```

Если скрипт повис, нажимаете Ctrl+Break и получаете запущенный отладчик в проблемном месте.

Если же нештатное поведение - это завершение работы без каких либо ошибок, то поможет [отладочное логирование](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). Добавляете `logger.debug(some_message, some_variable)` во все значимые места и после вылета скрипта анализируете последние сообщения.

А можно и совместить оба варианта.

Comment: а как можно контролировать использование памяти под стек рекурсивных вызовов и динамику расходования памяти вообще?
В моем примере есть такое "логирование"  --  это подсчет вызовов рекурсивной функции. Но - то нормальное завершение на 3636 вызове рекурсии, то - вылет на 1000+ вызове рекурсии....
Что еще добавлять?

Comment: В отладчике можно проанализировать стек вызовов. Можно дополнительно импортировать memory_profiler. В логи добавить логирование всех вызовов, условий и состояние переменных.