# Python периодически "падает" с ошибкой 0xc00000fd Windows10 x64

Tags: python, windows-10

То есть он работает на мелких задачах, а потом - "падает без слов"
Что надо делать?
Переинсталировать пайтон?
Переинсталировать винду?
Есть ли утилиты?
Сразу скажу - все обновлено и винда и питон
подробности [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771425/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B5)
А вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С этим лучше всего [сюда](https://docs.python.org/3.6/bugs.html).

Comment: А какой код возврата при падении?

Comment: да я уже писал - никакого...
Это выглядит так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1do06.png

Comment: Пробовали питоновское [виртуальное окружение](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)?

Comment: Это `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW           = $C00000FD;` значит вы что-то делаете такое что приводит к переполнению стека. Исходя из скрина - возможно где-то вы злоупотребляете рекурсией.

Comment: Во многих средах при переполнении стека падает вся программа. Если вы используете рекурсию - обязательно ограничивайте её глубину. Эта ошибка относится к особым ошибкам, она не ловится try-catch, ввиду того что многие функции используют стековые переменные - восстановление работы программы при такой ошибки не предусматривается обычно.

Comment: Попробуйте это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/Использование-рекурсии-более-1000-раз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW           =  0xC00000FD` - переполнение стека.

Большинство систем плохо обрабатывают эту ошибку, потому что эта ошибка вызывает
падение всего процесса.

Варианты решения проблемы:

1. Нужно ограничивать глубину рекурсии, и можно даже принудительно протестировать, что такая глубина подходит специально зациклив рекурсию.

Можно через [sys.setrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) установить меньше лимит на к-во вызовов, этим уменьшить глубину рекурсии.

Можно програмно - условно, вводим переменную-счетчик в аргумент, и делаем рекурсию вида `f(...,counter+1)` если counter превышает какое-то значение - делаем принудительно возврат или генерируем исключение.

2. Находим параметры "размер стека", увеличиваем этот параметр. Размер стека должен быть больше чем `макс_глубина_рекурсии*(размер_аргуметов+размер_служебной_области)`.  `размер_аргуметов` можно вычислить, он будет порядка 16...32 байт, но если много аргументов - будет достаточно большим. `размер_служебной_области` будет порядка 32 байт, он может быть от 4 байт до 32 байт. Задав правильно размер стека, при условии что рекурсия не бесконечная, или вызовов до 10тыс... до миллиона - то это сработает. Размер стека основной программы задаётся в опциях компилятора/линкера.
3. Ищем в сети библиотеки которые перехватывают механизм сбоя при переполнении стека, и правильно делают обработку этой ошибки.
4. Если есть опыт питон+WinAPI, читаем [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907230/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81) и пишем заглушку  на переполнение стека самостоятельно.
5. Отказаться от рекурсии там, где невозможно обеспечить целосность стека. Вместо рекурсии можно вполне использовать динамические списки, динамические массивы. Любую рекурсивную функцию можно переписать таким образом. Тогда ошибка вместо StackOverflow станет OutOfMemory, которая менее критична, и выходя из функции с маркером ошибки (по исключению) память будет освобождена, и программа будет работать более стабильно.
6. При использовании "хвостовой" рекурсии так же поможет (не все компиляторы умеет её преобразовывать).