# Использование рекурсии более 1000 раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Я новичок в программировании на Python(мой 1 язык программирования).
Решал задачу №12 из Проекта Эйлера. Я использовал рекурсию в функции, но к сожалению, чтобы решить задачу, придётся использовать рекурсию более 1000 раз. Хотел бы узнать, как решить эту задачу по-прежнему используя рекурсию, для того чтобы знать об этом в будущем.

Как можно улучшить код и что вы думаете о моих названиях переменных и функции?

Вот так звучит задача :

Последовательность треугольных чисел образуется путем сложения натуральных чисел. К примеру, 7-ое треугольное число равно 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. Первые десять треугольных чисел:

1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Перечислим делители первых семи треугольных чисел:
1: 1
3: 1, 3
6: 1, 2, 3, 6
10: 1, 2, 5, 10
15: 1, 3, 5, 15
21: 1, 3, 7, 21
28: 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28
Как мы видим, 28 - первое треугольное число, у которого более пяти делителей.

Каково первое треугольное число, у которого более пятисот делителей?

Вот мой код:

```
def tringle_number(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x + tringle_number(x-1)
for i in range(1, 900):
    a.append(tringle_number(i))
print(a)

need = 0
all_number = [1]
count = 0
for item in a:
    number = 0
    for j in range(1, 100000):
         if item % j == 0:
            count = j
            number += 1
            if number == 100:
                for items in all_number:
                    need += 1
                    if need == 1:
                        all_number.append(item)
                    else:
                        continue
         else:
            continue
print(all_number[1])
```

Comment: else: continue не нужно писать, это поведение по умолчанию.

Answer (score 5):

По умолчанию размер стека в Питоне ограничен 1000 вызовов. Обычно этого достаточно. Если вы пишете рекурсивный алгоритм (вам так нравится, или вы портируете код с Lisp, или вы фанат [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)) то это ограничение может серьёзно испортить настроение.

Ограничение можно ослабить вызовом [sys.setrecursionlimit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit). Этот вызов увеличит предел, но он не всесилен. В Питоне количество вызовов ограничено ещё и количеством памяти которая выделена под стек. Изнутри программы повлиять на размер стека нельзя. Если стек переполняется, то операционная система останавливает интерпретатор.

Выбор грустный: или программа упрётся в лимит самого интерпретатора и получит исключение

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

или программа будет остановлена с ошибкой

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Во втором случае ничего сделать нельзя. В первом случае есть возможность восстановиться после ошибки - и это причина по которой это, вроде бы бесполезное, ограничение существует.

Для примера: на моей системе CPython ломается при глубине стека примерно 21817.

Если этого вам мало, то посмотрите [The Stackless Python](https://github.com/stackless-dev/stackless). Он почти не использует аппаратный стек. На нем тоже нужно установить `sys.setrecursionlimit`. Я установил миллиард. Глубина рекурсии в 10 миллионов не проблема.

Для 100 миллионов не хватило 32GB памяти. В The Stackless Python один рекурсивный вызов занимает примерно 790 байт. 40 миллионов вызовов займут 32GB памяти.

Последнее ограничение преодолеть будет сложно. Если вам нужно больше, ищите другой интерпретатор (сообщите мне, как найдете) или другой язык (например с поддержкой оптимизации [хвостовой рекурсии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Answer (score 4):

рекурсия реализуется вызовом функции из самой себя

любой вызов функции, ее исполнение и выдачу результата выглядит так:

```
записать адрес точки возврата в стек
перейти в начало функции
выполнить функцию
извлечь из стека последнее число (адрес) и перейти по нему
```

когда выполняется рекурсия, то в стек пихаются адреса точки возврата и не выпихиваются обратно (пока рекурсия не опустится на самый глубокий уровень)

в определенный момент стек просто переполняется (поскольку не резиновый)

поэтому говорить "как сделать рекурсию без рекурсии" не очень корректно -

ответ такой - ОТКАЖИТЕЛЬ В ДАННОЙ ЗАДАЧЕ ОТ РЕКУРСИИ

**P.S.**

вот код без рекурсий (работает довольно быстро):

```
def count_dividers(value):
    count = 1

    dividers = set()

    for i in range(1, 2 + int(value**0.5)):
        if value % i == 0:
            if i not in dividers:
                dividers.add(i)
                dividers.add(value // i)

                count += 1 if i * i == value else 2

    return count


index = 1
while True:
    # получить треугольное число
    num = (1 + index) * index // 2
    index += 1

    # определить кол-во делителей числа
    if count_dividers(num) > 1000:
        print(num, index)
        break
```

вот этот код подсчета делителей более оптимальный (меньше проверок и действий):

```
def count_dividers(value):
    count = 0
    limit = math.floor(value**0.5)

    for i in range(1, limit + 1):
        if value % i == 0:
            count += 2

    count -= 1 if limit * limit == value else 0

    return count
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я разобрал ваш код и понял, что мне ещё учиться и учиться. Я почерпнул для себя много нового и полезного из вашего кода. Никогда бы не додумался до такой функции и цикла while.Ещё раз спасибо . Я также хотел бы узнать, почему вы рассматриваете 0 как один из делителей? Позиция нужного треугольного числа при подсчёте только натуральными числами(без 0) получается на 1 больше. Думаю нужно выводить в условии цикла index-1,  а в функции переменной count присвоить начальное значение 0 для более понятного(с точки зрения другого программиста) и корректного выполнения условия.

Comment: @Student7sk, если вы про `count = 1`, то конечно надо `count = 0`, это осталось от первой версии кода, когда я делители брал от `2` до `value`, затем я оптимизировал процесс снизив сложность с O(n) до O(sqrt(n)), а эту правку сделать забыл :( моя вина. P.S. кстати опять же я делал код на коленке и если сделать не `2 + int(value**0.5)`, а очень аккуратно выбрать верхнюю границу - т.е. `1 + int(math.floor(value**0.5))`, то можно полностью отказаться от `dividers` и проверки на вхождение в `dividers` и добавления в `dividers`, что заметно повысит скорость решения (у меня просто в лоб)

Comment: добавил пример более оптимизированного кода

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз! Мне стало нравится программирование ещё больше и появилась мотивация также писать алгоритмы на коленке, как вы:)

Answer (score 4):

> выполняется он конечно очень долго

```
for i in range(1, 900):
    a.append(tringle_number(i))
```

Подумайте, что здесь происходит. Что делает функция `tringle_number`, когда она вызывается с аргументом `898` и с аргументом `899`.

Answer (score 3):

я бы сделал так:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache
def tringle_number(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x + tringle_number(x-1)

def f(n):
    number = 0
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            number += 1
    return number
    
    
a = []
for i in range(1, 900):
    a.append(tringle_number(i))

for item in a:
    if f(item) >= 100:
        print(item)
        break
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Я понял, что рекурсия для данной задачи абсолютно не подходит. Но я разобрал ваш код и улучшил понимание алгоритмов. Спасибо ещё раз!