# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, рекурсия

Есть задача:

> Запишите рекурсивную функцию, вычисляющую сумму целых чисел `m` и `n`, в которой из арифметических операций используется только прибавление и вычитание единицы.

К сожалению, на значениях m, n = -10779,-15755 сталкиваюсь с исключением `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.
Попытка задать лимит для количества рекурсий не даёт результатов, когда целочисленные значения возрастают до 100 000 - память не позволяет приблизиться к этим числам.

Пока остановились с преподавателем на том, что эту задачу посредством Python 3.9 не решить.

Возможно здесь есть те, кто может доказать обратное. Хочется посмотреть какими средствами можно справиться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых, есть [Stackless Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackless_Python): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-1000-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7/1221205#1221205

Comment: @Stanislav, всё оч просто. Вот текст задачи, который нужно решить конкретно через рекурсию. Не идёт речи о том, что это хорошо/плохо. Речь идёт о том, чтобы исследовать python на возможность решения такой задачи. Я придумать ничего не смог.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отличная задача. Спасибо!

Чтобы обойти ограничение на глубину рекурсии нужно заменить линейную рекурсию на древовидную. Число операций в линейной рекурсии равно её глубине. Число операций в древовидной рекурсии можно довести до степени двойки от её глубины.

Функция `tree_add` может сделать до `level^2` операций. Если этого хватило чтобы обнулить `b` (второй элемент `p`), хорошо. Если нет, функция возвращает неполный результат.

```
# level - неотрицательное число
# p - пара чисел (a, b), которые нужно сложить
# если |b| <= 2^level, то функция вернёт (a + b, 0)
# иначе функция вернёт (a + 2^level, b - 2^level), если b > 0
# или                  (a - 2^level, b + 2^level), если b < 0
def tree_add(level, p):
    if level == 0:
        a, b = p
        if b == 0:
            return a, 0
        if b > 0:
            return a + 1, b - 1
        if b < 0:
            return a - 1, b + 1
    return tree_add(level - 1, tree_add(level - 1, p))
```

Функция `linear_add` вызывает `tree_add` до тех пор пока та не сумеет выполнить всю работу. Уровень каждый раз увеличивается на единицу, соответственно `tree_add` может выполнить в два раза больше работы:

```
def linear_add(level, p):
    a, b = tree_add(level, p)
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return linear_add(level + 1, (a, b))
```

Верхний уровень - просто сложение:

```
def add(a, b):
    return linear_add(0, (a, b))
```

Можно показать что глубина рекурсии не превосходит `2log2(b)`, что позволяет обрабатывать числа до `2^500`.

> ```
> @>>> add(1_000_000, 1_000_000)
> 2000000
> ```

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy - Вы шикарно обошли ограничения! Единственное не совсем понятное место: а аргументы в tree_add - симметричные? то есть, не имеет смысла заморачиваться, что там уровень, а что - число?

Comment: @S.H., добавил толстый комментарий в заголовок `tree_add`.

Comment: @S.H., спасибо. Да, решение изящное. Это третий вариант. Первые два были страшненькие. Но, может быть есть что-то ещё более изящное.

Comment: Нет, с таким изяшным решением соревноваться бесполезно! На самом деле, Вы своим ответм ума прибавили не только автору вопроса, но и "болельщикам"!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, это потрясающе!  Спасибо, что ещё раз вселили в меня уверенность, что в Python возможно всё.P.S., конечно, это не значит, что его надо сувать во все разные места.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще такую матрешку попробовать:

```
def rec_add(x,y):
    f = lambda a,b,i=1000: (a,b) if not i or b==0 else f(a+1,b-1,i-1) if b>0 else f(a-1,b+1,i-1)
    if y==0: return x
    return rec_add(*f(x,y))

rec_add(1000000,1000000)
'''
2000000
```

Comment: Упомяните что вам нужен `sys.setrecursionlimit(2002)` или больше.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, возможно. У меня питон 3.8, работает на значениях по умолчанию.

Comment: сделал `sys.getrecursionlimit()` показывает 3000

Comment: У меня Linux 64. Python 3.5, 3.7, 3.9, 3.10. Везде 1000.

Comment: Исходный код 3.8 - значение 1000 в исходном коде. Подозреваю что вы запускаете Питон не напрямую. Юпитер ноутбук?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да точно. Через Jupyter.

Comment: Данная матрёшка не обошла ограничение рекурсии.