# Как реализуется стек и куча в интерпретируемых языках?

Tags: python, c, компилятор, интерпретатор

1. Правильно ли я понимаю что когда запускается виртуальная машины например CPython ей ОС выделяем область памяти разбитую на стек и кучу, а дальше уже внутренний код ВМ сам делит кучу на как бы "вложенные" стек и кучу для python скрипта? Т.е. это уже реализация самой ВМ управляет стеком и кучей под которое она сама выделяет место в своей куче?

Или все же она обращается как то именно к стеку выделенному под процесс операционной системой?

2. Если в случае с компилируемыми языками у нас компилятор проходит весь текст программы и заменяет имя переменной на адрес смещения в стеке, то в случае интерпретируемых языков такой операции нет, тогда не совсем понимаю зачем нам вобще нужен стек, ведь мы не меняем именна переменных на адрес смещения, а видимо каждый раз при обращении к какой то переменной python скрипта ищем ее значение в какой то хеш таблице наверное? (где то же у нас должно храниться соответствие?)

Comment: Питон (cpython) во время работы использует системный стек. "Грамотными" настройками его можно переполнить и получить сбой типичный для обыкновенной C-программы.

Comment: Stackless Python не использует системный стек во время рекурсивных вызовов.

Comment: Тут есть разбор: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-1000-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7/1221205#1221205

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я честно говоря думал что работу со стеком реализует компилятор , а из самой программы с ним нельзя взаимодействовать , видимо можно ? И второй вопрос а что на счёт переменных как хранятся их имена + адреса где эта связка ?

Comment: Связка хранится в хеш таблице, но вот сама таблица хранится в стеке (апаратном или эмулируемом). Больше негде, ведь таких таблиц много. Во-первых, каждый вызов функции создает эту таблицу локальных переменных. И еще не забывайте, что стеков много - один на исполняемый поток.

Comment: Стеков ещё больше если в коде используются рекурсивные генераторы.

Comment: По моему, это несколько чрезмерно усложняет вопрос. В конечном счете у нас же всё равно есть некий обощённый стек (на уровне идеологии системы) и куча. От того, что стеков много, принцип же не меняется.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить при вызове процедуры запись в стеке создаётся. В ней должны быть ссылки на `globals`, `locals` и замыкание. Все таблицы в куче, в стеке только указатели на них.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, так и есть. И живёт все это там, пока процедура живёт.

Comment: Я хотел сказать что интерпретатор эмулирует много стеков в куче и использует системный стек (cpython) или не использует его совсем (stackless python).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можете пояснить какая именно работа происходит именно системным стеком, можем ли мы прям в него добавлять хеш таблицы с данными из питон кода, это мы его используем именно с точки зрения Си программы? Ну тоесть я хочу представить что именно лежит в стеке ВМ , а что лежит в стеке питона который на самом деле находится в куче ВМ.

Comment: При вызове функции на Python происходит вызов функции на C: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Python/ceval.c#L4213. Все данные Питона лежат на несистемном стеке (он выделен в куче), но интерпретатор пользуется системным стеком чтобы запоминать порядок вызова функций. То есть, если вы напишите на C расширение для Питона вы сможете работать с системным стеком.

Comment: Переменные Питона все лежат в куче, включая питоновский стек. Вам может быть интересно https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals. Когда вы "добавляете переменную" она попадает в хеш-таблицу `locals`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy понял спасибо. Но под "работать с системным стеком" подразумевается что создание переменных нужных нам дополнительно для интепретации и т.п. тем самым мы изменяем системный стек. Напрямую написать код который прям делает какие то действия с системным стеком мы ведь не можем? Я сначала подумал что речь про это.

Answer (score 1):

Для СPython :
Реализация самой ВМ управляет стеком и кучей (как и сборкой мусора). Сверху стек, снизу куча.
В стеке - ссылки на объекты в куче. Фактических значений в стеке нет.
Все объекты и структуры данных (т.е. и переменные и значения) - в куче.Управляет ей внутренний менеджер памяти.

Напонимню, что в CPython переменная - не то же самое, что в C. Тут это просто имя, ссылающееся на PyObject/PyListObject.

Нашел ещё ссылку прямо тут со 131 одобрением, но особо ничего принципиального она к моему тексту не добавляет:-)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546178/does-python-have-a-stack-heap-and-how-is-memory-managed

Comment: Это немного не то что я хотел узнать, можете дополнить на примере пожалуйста.
Вот запустилась у нас ВМ (это исполняевый файл на Си) ей выделился стек и куча.
Начинается исполняться код на python "a = 5", в этот момент в стек добавляется хеш таблица в Си реализации, в которую кладется связка {а : 5}, дальше допустим вызывается процедура соответственно добавляется еще одна хеш таблица в стек, с окружением этой процедуры, примерно так?

Comment: точнее даже в стек добавилась не сама хеш таблица, а указатель на нее

Comment: Я вижу так: ВМ CPython "живёт" в куче. Её стек находится там же с точки зрения ОС (см.ссылку). Это эмуляция. Как используется системный стек - возможно, пояснит @Stanislav Volodarskiy. 
В момент "a=5"  в куче создаётся PyObject, куда эта 5 и попадает (также там тип и счетчик ссылок). "а" со ссылкой на этот PyObject размещается в стеке ВМ. В форме ли хэш-таблицы это делается? - скорее всего. 
Когда вызывается функция, используется стек вызовов функций, в него будет помещено на время жизни функции всё, что будет инициировано (у вас: " добавляется еще одна хеш таблица ").

Comment: Вот ещё достаточно интересная ссылка: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149013/what-does-it-mean-that-python-is-stack-based>

Comment: Спасибо. Я примерно так же и представлял все. Тут остается вопрос все таки об использовании системного стека ВМ. Я пока не могу представить что можно им как то пользоваться, т.е. даже когда я просто пишу программу на Си я не совсем понимаю как можно что-то делать со своим же стеком. Поидеи это компилятор делает, присваивает переменной смешение, увеличивает указатель стека, далее новым переменным присваивает новый указатель и опять его увеличивает. Не совсем понимаю как мы можем в него сами что-то добавить\удалить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можете пояснить какая именно работа происходит именно системным стеком, можем ли мы прям в него добавлять хеш таблицы с данными из питон кода, это мы его используем именно с точки зрения Си программы? Ну тоесть я хочу представить что именно лежит в стеке ВМ , а что лежит в стеке питона который на самом деле находится в куче ВМ.

Comment: Вопрос основной не "как", а "зачем"? Он же системный. Если нужен стек свой для чего-то создать в куче. Полагаю, рисков получим больше, чем преимуществ, отправляясь в системный стек. Кроме того, Python - не С. Он более высокоуровневый. Ряд вопросов, ещё имеющих смысл в C для практической реализации, в Python уже лучше не трогать, по-моему, на уровне разработчика скриптов, как минимум.