# ограничения рекурсии в python

Tags: python, рекурсия

почему рекурсия выполняется только 995 раз? и как это можно исправить?

Comment: У Cpython есть ограничение на рекурсию, да, исправить можно с помощью вот этого

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

Comment: Второй способ - вообще её не использовать. Любой алгоритм (на Python точно) можно написать без неё. Слишком  большая вложенность может говорить о неоптимальном алгоритме.

Comment: Увеличить предел можно попробовать (как - написано выше), но делать это не рекомендуется, потому что если вы не угадаете с лимитом, то при превышении определённого предела вылетит не просто исключение выполнения кода, а конкретно грохнется уже сам интерпретатор питона. В целом, лучше рекурсию в питоне использовать только в учебных целях.

Comment: а как можно быстро найти факториал большого числа, допустим, 37826497? у рекурсии на столько не растягивается лимит, а через цикл попробовал-слишком долго 

Comment: @артемкостриков А почему вы думаете, что через рекурсию будет быстрее?! )))  Наоборот, при рекурсии будет всегда медленнее, потому что вызовы функции будут забивать данными стек и т.д. Хотел предложить вам использовать библиотеку `Numba` для ускорения, но для неё это тоже слишком большие числа, переполнение происходит. В простом то питоне целые числа бесконечные, но из-за этого они не оптимальные по скорости.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку в комментарии речь зашла про конкретный случай, предлагаю как вариант метод быстрый, но, увы, не сильно точный. Зато считается примерно секунду на предложенном автором вопроса числе:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit()
def factorial(n):
    s = 1
    d = 0
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        s *= i
        while s >= 10:
            s /= 10
            d += 1
    return s,d

s,d = factorial(37_826_497)
print(f'{s}e+{d}')
```

Вывод:

```
4.349383396225913e+270213647
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @артемкостриков Но вы понимаете, что тут только где-то цифр 20 первых от факториала и порядок (степень 10) правильные, а чтобы посчитать прямо все цифры факториала вам придётся всё-таки чистым питоном воспользоваться и долго ждать? )

Answer (score 1):

Можно увеличить глубину рекурсии до примерно 22000 (так было когда-то, на Python 3.10 предел 14542 на моей машине). Можно сменить интерпретатор Питона на безстековый - глубина рекурсии будет ограничена только доступной памятью: около 40 миллионов вызовов на 32GB. Последнего числа вам будет достаточно если вы напишете программу достаточно правильно. ([Разбор рекурсии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-1000-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7/1221205#1221205))

По времени работы рекурсивная и итеративная программы будут одинаковы: и там и там всё время уйдёт на последовательные умножения. Накладные расходы на цикл или на рекурсию вы даже не заметите.

В соседнем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1402202/416121) факториал считается приблизительно последовательным умножением и отбрасыванием младших цифр. Ещё один способ - заменить умножение числе на сложение их натуральных логарифмов. Натуральный логарифм перевести в десятичный и напечатать его:

```
import numpy as np


def big_factorial(n):
    i = np.arange(2, n + 1)
    lg = np.sum(np.log(i)) / np.log(10)
    m, e = np.modf(lg)
    return 10 ** m, int(e)


m, e = big_factorial(int(input()))
print(f'{m}e+{e}')
```

> ```
> $ time echo 37826497 | python big-factorial.py
> 4.349383221475161e+270213647
>
> real  0m1.153s
> user  0m1.212s
> sys   0m0.552s
> ```

Семь знаков этого ответа совпадают с соседним ответом, который, как сейчас станет ясно, более точный.

Можно ли получить точные цифры? Да, можно. Этот код за полтора часа вычисляет факториал и выводит его старшие цифры точно:

```
import math


n, d = map(int, input().split())
f = math.factorial(n);
e = int(f.bit_length() / math.log(10, 2)) - d
b = 10 ** e
print(f'{f // b}...')
```

> ```
> $ time echo 37826497 20 | python big-factorial-exact.py 
> 434938339623008896624...
>
> real  89m13.142s
> user  89m7.112s
> sys   0m2.428s
> ```

Можно точно оценить интервал в котором лежит факториал. Потребуется меньше минуты:

```
def factorial(n, d):
    e = 0
    m = 10 ** d
    low = 1
    high = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        low *= i
        c = 0
        while low >= m:
            low //= 10
            c += 1
        f = 10 ** c
        e += c

        high = (high * i + f - 1) // f
    return low, high, e


n, d = map(int, input().split())
low, high, e = factorial(n, d)
print(low, f'* 10^{e}')
print(high, f'* 10^{e}')
```

> ```
> $ time echo 37826497 20 | python big-factorial-interval.py 
> 43493833962268738973 * 10^270213628
> 43493833962333044522 * 10^270213628
>
> real  0m47.203s
> user  0m47.196s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Comment: Это в какой версии питона можно до 22000 рекурсию увеличить? Я где пробовал там хорошо если 1500-2000 максимум было, а дальше всё :(

Comment: @CrazyElf, глубина 14542 на Python 3.10/Linux 64.