# Простые решения проблем с рекурсией

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия, производительность

При выполнении сложных учебных задач (например, на алгоритмы или структуры данных) у многих (и у меня) периодически возникают проблемы из-за использования рекурсии. Либо превышается допустимый размер стека, либо программа выполняется дольше, чем допустимо по условию. В реальной работе это будет означать медленную работу программы либо неэффективное использование ресурсов компьютера.

При этом не очень легко найти поиском простые способы ухода от таких проблем, статьи чаще о сложных случаях, приходится придумывать, а при отсутствии навыка это может быть не быстро. Здесь предлагается поместить небольшую коллекцию простых методов (идеально, если читающие добавят их сами в виде ответов). Лучше с фокусом на Python, но принципиально большинство должно по логике подходить для многих языков программирования.
Полагаю, сообществу должно быть полезно иметь это в базе знаний.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220820/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-1000-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7/1221205#1221205

Comment: Если рекурсивную функцию удалось переписать в форму [хвостовой рекурсии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), то переход к циклу делается автоматически. Если функция сложная, то можно сделать итерацию с использованием массива в качестве стека. Если всё ещё сложнее, можно построить дерево вызовов, которое обрабатывается итеративно.

Comment: "папа, а ты с кем разговариваешь?":-) И что значит "автоматически" - это значит "просто" или это значит, что компилятор сам переведет?

Comment: "автоматически" - (не сложно) делается руками программиста, знакомого с инструкцией.

Comment: Так все простые методы делаются "автоматически". Просто мне в час ночи подумать все же пришлось минут 15. Вот и записал результат размышлений ("мама, я открыл второй закон Ньютона!":-)).

Comment: Я не увидел что тут самоответ. В качестве упражнения попробуйте написать итеративную версию `quicksort`. Опыт решения этой задачи многое расставляет по местам.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, cпасибо, я изучал быструю сортировку <https://stepik.org/lesson/13249/step/1?unit=3434>. И код с элиминированием хвостовой рекурсии делал. Там он посложнее все же, чем тут. "Массива в качестве стека" и "дерево вызовов, которое обрабатывается итеративно" там не было, правда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот несколько **самых простых способов** на Python (скорее всего, легко портируются и для других языков).

Все их реально применил при решении мной вчера задачи на Stepik (там более сложные примеры, конечно, были, тут упростил для понимания читающих), да и в других случаях применял:

*1) При проблеме с допустимой глубиной рекурсии*, если не избавляться от самой рекурсии:*

надо добавить в код строку `sys.setrecursionlimit (50000)` - параметр в скобках с таким большим значением во всех моих случаях решал вопрос (по умолчанию этот параметр равен 1000 или чуть менее, в первом примере ниже ошибка появится при `a = 998`).
Требуется ещё `import sys`,конечно.

Повторю, что было написано в начальном вопросе: "В реальной работе это будет означать медленную работу программы либо неэффективное использование ресурсов компьютера". Лучше это не применять без большой необходимости.

*встречавшиеся мне ошибки при превышении глубины рекурсии:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` и

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

*2) При рекурсивном вызове в конце функции:*

```
def test (a):
    a -= 1
    if a > 0:
        print (a)
    else:
        return
    test(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 997
    test (a)
```

переделать функцию можем просто с помощью `while True`, уйдя от рекурсии:

```
def test (a):
    while True:
        a -= 1
        if a > 0:
            print (a)
        else:
            return
```

*3) При варианте чуть сложнее с рекурсивными вызовами в середине функции:*

```
def test(a, b):
    print ('test start, a, b', a, b)
    if a > 5:
        print('condition a')
        return test(a-1, b)
    if b < 5:
        print('condition b')
        return test(a, b+1)
    print ('test finish, a, b', a, b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   a = 7
   b = 3
```

надо еще добавить `continue` и `break`, чтобы уйти от рекурсии, помимо `while True`:

```
def test(a, b):
    while True:
        print ('test start, a, b', a, b)
        if a > 5:
            print('condition a')
            a -= 1 
            continue
        if b < 5:
            print('condition b')
            b += 1
            continue
        print('test finish, a, b', a, b)
        break
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137585/discussion-on-answer-by------).