# Как работает рекурсивная функция, Python

Tags: python, рекурсия

Есть вот такая функция

```
    def get_line_list(d, a=[]):
        for i in d:
            if type(i) != list:
                a.append(i)
            else:
                get_line_list(i)
        return a
    
    
    print(get_line_list([1, 2, [True, False], ["Москва", "Уфа", [100, 101], ['True', [-2, -1]]], 7.89]))
```

Первый параметр - многомерный список, второй параметр - пустой список, в который нужно переместить все элементы из первого и при этом распаковать их, чтобы список в итоге вышел одномерным.

Вопрос: в какой вообще момент рекурсивная функция здесь распаковывает списки? Как это происходит?

Второй вопрос: насколько вообще нужно запариваться над темой рекурсии, часто ли она применяется на практике? Это какой-то мрак и хотелось бы знать, стоит ли вообще мучиться и понимать её?

Comment: Вызовите `get_line_list` два раза в одной программе. Будет интересно, обещаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

"Распаковывается" список в момент, когда рекурсивная функция, начинает работать со списком.
Сначала `for i in d` идет по начальному списку. Затем, как только `if type(i) != list`обнаруживает, что компонент `[True, False]` - список, то идет рекурсовный вызов и `for i in d` в вызванной функции "распаковывает" этот мини-список. И так далее.

Советую посмотреть самому в пошаговом отладчике, что происходит, а то голову сломаете. Вот ссылка на другой мой ответ, где про отладчик самое необходимое говорится (ну, или `print` используйте, про него там тоже есть):
[Ошибка в коде генерации пароля. Просьба помочь найти причину, дать пояснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423731/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/1423738#1423738)

2.
Рекурсия применяется не очень часто, но применяется. Понимать её надо, хотя бы для того, чтобы знать, как переделать алгоритм, чтобы от нёё избавиться. В Python любую программу можно переписать  без рекурсии, но иногда это будет сложно. Лучше жить без неё (быстрее работает код, как правило, на стек меньше нагрузка), но в алгоритмах она встречается.

Вот ссылка на простые советы, как от неё избавляться в базовых случаях:
[Простые решения проблем с рекурсией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1427216/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9/1427217#1427217)

Comment: то есть распаковка в саму рекурсию автоматом заложена получается? Спасибо, странная тема, но стало немного понятнее

Comment: Нет в рекурсии никакой особой распаковки. У вас и обычная функция так же будет со списком работать.  Взяла список, и пошла по нему. В вашем случае на вход рекурсивной функции приходит обычный список, с ним она и работает. Посмотрите обязательно (отладчиком или `print (d)`, например), как это происходит по шагам.

Comment: Всё, посмотрел, разобрался. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, мнѣ эта функція очень не нравится. Условіе съ двумя отрицаніями, неявная передача параметра, и вообще… Но если не переписывать всё съ нуля, а только причесать имѣющееся, то я бы такъ сдѣлалъ:

```
def get_line_list(d):
    a = []
    for i in d:
        if type(i) == list:
            a.extend(get_line_list(i))
        else:
            a.append(i)
    return a
```

Что касается того, зачѣмъ нужна рекурсія, то это странный вопросъ. Затѣмъ же, зачѣмъ и любой другой инструментъ, пусть даже абстрактный. Очень часто рекурсивное рѣшеніе получается самоочевиднымъ, изящнымъ и лапидарнымъ. Рекомендую порѣшать задачи на рекурсию. Вотъ мой любимый примѣръ: написать функцію, которая изъ трёхъ чиселъ выбираетъ среднее, т. е. такое, которое располагается на числовой оси между двумя остальными. Попробуйте придумать, гдѣ тамъ примѣнить рекурсію.

Comment: А зачем вы дореформенной орфографией пользуетесь? В правилах сайта, конечно, не догадались написать, что русский язык должен соответствовать нормам современной орфографии, но неудобно же читать.